# PHP: как записать данные после обработки в переменную?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть переменная $content содержимое которой, я обрабатываю следующим образом:

```
$dom = new DomDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$dom->loadHTML( $content );
$xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
$elements = $xpath->query( '//body/div/node()[normalize-space()]' );

foreach( $elements as $element ) {

  if( $element->nodeName == '#text' ) {

    foreach( preg_split( "/\\r?\\n/", $element->c14n() ) as $text_string ) {
      trim( $text_string, " \t\0\x0B" ) . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
    }

  }

  else {
    trim( $element->c14n(), " \t\0\x0B" ) . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
  }

}

-----------------------------

??? return|echo $content; ???
```

Как мне ЗДЕСЬ (после обработки), вернуть обработанные данные снова в переменную $content - для вывода или дальнейшей обаботки?

Спасибо!

Comment: а где у вас данные обрабатываются? Вы вызываете фунции(`trim`), полностью игнорируя их результат.

Answer (score 1):

Заверните ваш код в функцию:

```
function handle($content) {
    $ret = [];
    $dom = new DomDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
    $dom->loadHTML( $content );
    $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
    $elements = $xpath->query( '//body/div/node()[normalize-space()]' );

    foreach( $elements as $element ) {

      if( $element->nodeName == '#text' ) {

        foreach( preg_split( "/\\r?\\n/", $element->c14n() ) as $text_string ) {
          $ret[] = trim( $text_string, " \t\0\x0B" ) . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
        }

      } else {
        $ret[] = trim( $element->c14n(), " \t\0\x0B" ) . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
      }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

и вызывайте:

```
$content = handle($content);
foreach ($content as $line) {
    print $line;
}
```